# C# draw ellipse on mouse click on Form

Tags: c#, drawing, ellipse

I pretty new at drawing in C#
I wanted to draw ellipses on Form on mouse click. I wrote a code but it doesn't want to draw on mouse click. Here's my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
    SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = CreateGraphics();

        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            p.Color = Color.Red;
            b.Color = Color.Red;

            }
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            p.Color = Color.Yellow;
            b.Color = Color.Yellow;

            }
        if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            p.Color = Color.Blue;
            b.Color = Color.Blue;

            }
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            g.FillEllipse(b, e.X, e.Y, 50, 50);

        else
            g.DrawEllipse(p, e.X, e.Y, 50, 50);
            g.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should not use `CreateGraphics` to hijack the drawing surface of a control.  When the Form repaints, anything that you have drawn in this manner will disappear.  Also you are not disposing of your `Pen` and `SolidBrush` resources so you have a leak of GDI resources.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `CreateGraphics` to hijack the drawing surface of a control. When the Form repaints, anything that you have drawn in this manner will disappear. Also you are not disposing of your `Pen` and `SolidBrush` so you have a leak of GDI resources.

Instead, create a list of ellipses to be drawn and then draw them in the Form `OnPaint` override.

Something like this:

First create a class to represent your shape:

```
public class Ellipse
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    public bool Filled { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when the mouse is clicked on the form, create a new instance of the shape and add it to a list.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //A list to hold all the ellipses to be drawn
    private List<Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Ellipse>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //When the form is clicked, create a new ellipse and add it to the list.
        ellipses.Add(new Ellipse
        {
            Color = radioButton1.Checked ? Color.Red : (radioButton2.Checked ? Color.Yellow : Color.Blue),
            Location = e.Location,
            Size = new Size(50, 50),
            Filled = checkBox1.Checked
        });

        //Tell the form to redraw itself
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Redraw each ellipse in the list.
        foreach (var ellipse in ellipses)
        {
            if (ellipse.Filled)
            {
                //Use a using block to make sure the resource is disposed
                using (var b = new SolidBrush(ellipse.Color))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, new Rectangle(ellipse.Location, ellipse.Size));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Use a using block to make sure the resource is disposed
                using (var p = new Pen(ellipse.Color))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, new Rectangle(ellipse.Location, ellipse.Size));                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or create your `SolidBrush` and `Pen` as instance variables and reuse them.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: I'm fairly new to drawing user (custom) controls; yet I've achieved a couple. Can you please provide further info to your answer?
Like: Why "You should not use CreateGraphics to hijack the drawing surface of a control. When the Form repaints, anything that you have drawn in this manner will disappear" and a detailled solution to it so that someone learning could understand how it should be done? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

the problem could be something else than the draw function.

I simplified it to test it and it worked for me:

```
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
    SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        p.Color = Color.Blue;
        b.Color = Color.Blue;
        g.FillEllipse(b, e.X, e.Y, 50, 50);
        g.DrawEllipse(p, e.X, e.Y, 50, 50);
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: CreateGraphics is temporary.  Don't use it.  Use the paint event of the container.

Comment: Interestingly this answer was the ONLY one that actually showed something. The answer from Chris simply didn't do anything,